# extracting numbers and dates from text (a vector of sentence-like strings) using R

Tags: r

I am trying to pull numbers and dates from text using R.  Say I have a vector of text strings, V.text.  The text strings are sentences that contain numbers and dates.  For example:

```
"listed on 2/14/2015 for 150000 and sold for $160,000 on 3/1/2015"
```

I want to extract the number amounts for and dates as separate vector components. 
So the output would be two vectors:

```
1  1500000 160000
2  2/14/2015 3/1/2015
```

I tried using `scan()` but couldn't get the desired result.  I would appreciate any help

Comment: this is probably not a great idea (so not worth an answer), but `s <- strsplit(gsub('[,$]','', string), ' ')[[1]]; Filter(Negate(is.na), as.numeric(s)); 
Filter(Negate(is.na), as.Date(s, '%m/%d/%Y'))`, ie, string split, coerce everything to numeric (or date), and filter out those that dont work

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
txt <- "listed on 2/14/2015 for 150000 and sold for $160,000 on 3/1/2015"
lapply(c('[0-9,]{5,}',
         '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}'),
       function(re) {
           matches <- gregexpr(re, txt)
           gsub(',', '', regmatches(txt, matches)[[1]])
       })
## [[1]]
## [1] "150000" "160000"
## [[2]]
## [1] "2/14/2015" "3/1/2015"
```

(The first match for numbers assumes 5 digits or more. If you have less, than this simpler regular expression will collide with the year of the date(s).)

Answer (score 2):

First split out the "words". Then the ones with a slash are dates and the ones with only $, digit or comma are numbers.  In the latter case strip off the non-digit characters and convert to numeric:

```
s <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]

grep("/", s, value = TRUE) # dates
## [1] "2/14/2015" "3/1/2015" 

as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", grep("^[$0-9,]+$", s, value = TRUE)))
## [1] 150000 160000
```

If negative numbers or decimal numbers are possible then change the last line of code to:

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^-0-9.]", "", grep("^-?[$0-9,.]+$", s, value = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Might want to add a decimal point in the acceptable characters (except for end of sentence periods.)

Comment: Strong work as always. I basically learned most of what I know about regex by goning back on forth between your posts on Rhelp and the `?regex` page.

Answer (score 1):

Quick-and-dirty approach:

```
x<-"listed on 2/14/2015 for 150000 and sold for $160,000 on 3/1/2015"
mydate<-regmatches(x,gregexpr("\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}",x,perl=TRUE))
mynumber<-regmatches(sub(",","",x),gregexpr("\\d{6}",sub(",","",x),perl=TRUE))
```

You can run the above code in [r-fiddle](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=DoLVghWn&version=1):